# How can I use json response from php in jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to do a website. I need to get all the reviews in the database. My initial guess was to use php like this:

```
function get_all_reviews(){
    $db = dbConnection();
    $db -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $query = "SELECT Nome, Title, reviews.Review, users.Email FROM `users` JOIN `reviews` WHERE users.Email = reviews.Email; ";
    $statement = $db -> prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll(); 
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $name = $row["Nome"];
        $title = $row["Title"];
        $review = $row["Review"];
        $email = $row["Email"];
        ?>
    <div class="box" id="<?= $email ?>">
    <div class="nome"><?= $name ?>  dice:</div>
    <div class="titolo"><?= $title ?> </div>
    <div class="recensione"><?= $review ?> </div>
    <button class="admin_bottom">X</button>
  </div>
    <?php    
}
```

But since it's a project for the university, I need to not use it (it's mandatory). I need to send the request with jquery, then with php I should send the response with json, but I don't get how to recall the reviews and list them.
I try with this with php:

```
function gett_all_reviews(){
        $db = dbConnection();
        $db -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $query = "SELECT Nome, Title, reviews.Review, users.Email FROM `users` JOIN `reviews` WHERE users.Email = reviews.Email; ";
        $statement = $db -> prepare($query);
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetchAll(); 
        $resultSet = '{ ';
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            $resultSet .= '{"name": "'.$row["Nome"].'",';
            $resultSet .= '"title": "'.$row["Title"].'",';
            $resultSet .= '"review": "'.$row["Review"].'",';
            $resultSet .= '"email": "'.$row["Email"].'"},';
    
        }
        $resultSet .= '}';
        $db = null;
    
        
        return $resultSet;
    }
    $s = get_all_reviews();
    
    echo $s;
```

and with jquery:

```
$.getJSON( "../php/get_reviews.php", function( json ) {
        
        for (let index = 0; index < json.length; index++) {
            $("#conteiner_reviews").append(
                "<div class=\"box\" id= \""+ json[index].email+ "\">"+
                    "<div class=\"nome\">"+json[index].name +" dice:</div>" +
                    "<div class=\"titolo\"><"+json[index].title+"</div>"+
                    "<div class=\"recensione\">"+json[index].review +"</div></div>");
        }
    });
```

But doesn't work.

Comment: Don't create JSON by concatenating strings. Create an array and then use `echo json_encode($array)`

Comment: Your JSON is not correct. You have `{}` around the array instead of `[]`, and you have an extra `,` after the last object in the array.

Answer (score -1):

```php
function gett_all_reviews(){
    $db = dbConnection();
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $query = "SELECT Nome as name, Title as title, reviews.Review as review, users.Email as email FROM `users` JOIN `reviews` WHERE users.Email = reviews.Email; ";
    $statement = $db -> prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll(); 
    $db = null;
    return $result;
}

echo json_encode(get_all_reviews());
```

```js
$.getJSON('../php/get_reviews.php', function (data) {
  $.each(data, function (item) {
    $('#conteiner_reviews').append(
      '<div class="box" id="' + item.email+ '">' +
      '<div class="nome">' + item.name + 'dice:</div>' +
      '<div class="titolo">' + item.title + '</div>' +
      '<div class="recensione">' + item.review + '</div>'
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: with jquery i used the $.each(data, function....   Anyway, it loads the boxes, but in the values it prints "undefined".

Comment: Hi @cristoball92. I have updated SQL query logic to get exact value to Jquery item variable. Please check updated code and let me know if it is working for you.